# Pandas Get Day of Week from date type column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Python 3.6 and Pandas 0.20.3.

I have a column that I've converted to date type from datetime. All I need is the date. I have it as a derived column for ease of use. But I'm looking to do some further operations via a day of the week calculation. I can get the day of week from a datetime type but not from the date. It seems to me that this should be possible but I've tried multiple variations and not found success.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-5-16','2017-5-17']})
df['trade_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

I can get the day of the week from the datetime column 'trade_date'.

```
df['dow']=df['trade_date'].dt.dayofweek
df
    date    trade_date  dow
0   2017-5-16   2017-05-16  1
1   2017-5-17   2017-05-17  2
```

But if I have a date, rather than a datetime, no dice:
For instance:

```
df['trade_date_2']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
```

And then:

```
df['dow_2']=df['trade_date_2'].dt.dayofweek
```

I get (at the end):

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

I've tried various combinations of dayofweek(), weekday, weekday() which, I realize, highlight my ignorance of exactly how Pandas works. So ... any suggestions besides adding another column which is the datetime version of column trade_date?
I'll also welcome explanations of why this is not working.

Comment: When you've `pd.Timestamp` type column why are still looking to use `datetime.date` objects?

Comment: You need to convert it back pandas datetime to use .dt accessor

Comment: @Zero That's a fair question (though it does not answer my question :) ). I believe that it made some comparison operations that I did elsewhere easier/possible. I say 'believe' because at this point I've been trying to absorb so much pandas/python so quickly, my memory is hazy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is problem it is difference between `pandas datetime` (timestamps) where are implemented `.dt` methods and `python date` where not.

```
#return python date
df['trade_date_2']= pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date

print (df['trade_date_2'].apply(type))
0    <class 'datetime.date'>
1    <class 'datetime.date'>
Name: trade_date_2, dtype: object

#cannot work with python date
df['dow_2']=df['trade_date_2'].dt.dayofweek
```

Need convert to `pandas datetime`:

```
df['dow_2']= pd.to_datetime(df['trade_date_2']).dt.dayofweek

print (df)
        date trade_date_2  dow_2
0  2017-5-16   2017-05-16      1
1  2017-5-17   2017-05-17      2
```

So the best is use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print (df['date'].apply(type))
0    <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
1    <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
Name: date, dtype: object

df['trade_date_2']= df['date'].dt.date
df['dow_2']=df['date'].dt.dayofweek
print (df)
        date trade_date_2  dow_2
0 2017-05-16   2017-05-16      1
1 2017-05-17   2017-05-17      2
```

EDIT:

Thank you [Bharath shetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515267/pandas-get-day-of-week-from-date-type-column/46515328#comment79984903_46515328) for solution working with `python date` - failed with `NaT`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-5-16',np.nan]})

df['trade_date_2']= pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
df['dow_2'] = df['trade_date_2'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday())
```

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'weekday'

Comparing solutions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-5-16','2017-5-17']})
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

def a(df):
    df['trade_date_2']= pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
    df['dow_2'] = df['trade_date_2'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday()) 
    return df

def b(df):
    df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    df['trade_date_21']= df['date1'].dt.date
    df['dow_21']=df['date1'].dt.dayofweek
    return (df)

def c(df):
    #dont write to column, but to helper series 
    dates = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    df['trade_date_22']= dates.dt.date
    df['dow_22']=        dates.dt.dayofweek
    return (df)

In [186]: %timeit (a(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 101 ms per loop

In [187]: %timeit (b(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 90.8 ms per loop

In [188]: %timeit (c(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 91.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: That is my current solution. It just seems like the python date type ought to have a dayofweek type of method.

Comment: Exactly. pandas need datetime (timestamps)

Comment: @kdragger If you want python to take care then `df['trade_date_2'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday())`

Comment: @Bharathshetty  why does that work? why can't I then do df['dow_2']=df['trade_date_2'].weekday() ?

Comment: @kdragger language please. Its because series don have weekday functionality and  needs to loop through every date to get the datetime value then you can use weekday() accessor.

Comment: @jezrael that was just to give pythonic way. But pd.to_datetime is better always

Comment: @Bharathshetty :) you have never seen "What the Fudge"? I appreciate the answer, but my oh my, it just makes my head hurt. It just seems so odd.

Comment: Well Im used to slang :)

Comment: @jezrael to be fair to the timing of the pd.to_datetime method, you need to add the creation of the column. As that is not necessary to the apply solution. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: Sure, Give me a sec.