# Pandas date time with day of the week

Tags: pandas

I’m doing a pandas read excel function to store the data as a data frame. One of the columns has a day of the week, date and time all combined together. The function is reading that column as an integer. I don’t know how to convert it to day of the week and date time all together format.

Comment: Can you create small data sample, 2-3 rows?

Comment: Sounds like you need to split the column first.  Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333299/splitting-a-column-by-delimiter-pandas-python (google pandas split column etc.) and then set the new columns to date, day of week.  Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515267/pandas-get-day-of-week-from-date-type-column or more googling for pandas set day of week on a column etc.

Comment: Tue 3/31 8:30 AM 
Wed 4/1 4:30 AM .... this is how the dates look in the column. Im trying to pd.to_datetime but its not giving the right date